# Display helptext on picklist values on hovering

Tags: helptext

I have a requirement to display help texts for all picklist values on hovering. It is a custom picklist field with 30 values. I know this can be achievable with visualforce but would like to know the complexity !

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want a different tooltip to show depending on which picklist value is selected? That isn't something that Visualforce provides.

Comment: Yes, like a tooltip. when the user mouse over each of the values, it should display a helptext appropriate to each value. Is there any alternative to achieve this ?

Comment: You will have to roll your own. It can be done using HTML CSS and data attributes on the li. But then it's not sf related. Similar can be achieved with apex:repeat and building the options and using jquery. Several other ways as well. All of which is off topic or too broad without you first giving it a shot

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I can see is having some text beside the picklist and some code to change this text based on your choice.
You can achieve this via apex using an action and rerender, or for better performance use Javascript to keep it client side.
Regarding complexity, I would say best practice is to create an object / custom setting that has picklist value and description to make future changes to help text declarative.
[Apex:selectList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) has a onmouseover attribute that you can use to call your Javascript. Assuming you loaded all the values of the custom list in your page, you can then use Javascript to fill the value.

Below is high level example

```
<apex:page action={!loadValues}>
  <script language="javascript">
      function showHelpText() {
         document.getElementById('your text').value = required value;
         //make the item visible
      }
     function hideHelptext(){
       //hide the label element
   </script>

   <apex:selectlist onmouseover="showHelpText()" onmouseout="hideHelptext()"/>
   //use this label to show help text
   <apex:label id="">
</apex:page>
```